# Corrections for logistic regression (multiple comparisons?)

Tags: logistic, multiple-comparisons, multivariate-regression, ecology, capture-mark-recapture

I'll cut to the chase.  Here's what I'm doing:

- looking at the influence of water temperature and salinity on the presence of water-borne parasites for a certain estuarine bird population
- birds are checked for parasites 3 times a year for 5 years (Spring, Summer, Fall)
- this is mark-recapture, and some birds are sampled multiple times across years and seasons
- logistic regression is for water temp and salinity predicting parasites

Since some birds are included multiple times in my dataset (some twice a year, and many in multiple years), would it be wise to correct for multiple comparisons (Boneffori?) or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to investigate some form of multi-level model (also known as mixed effects model). The Bonferroni correction is not going to help you here as far as I can see.

Comment: As mdeway says, a mixed effects model should work. You can add "bird" as a random effect.

Comment: This looks like a repeated measures design. That means incorporating the repeated measures into the statistics.

Comment: Thank you all!  Mixed effects sounds like the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As other comments have pointed out **Bonferroni correction** is not the right way to control for dependent grouping factors. You would use such a correction if you ran multiple models and want to account for multiple testing.

Try using a **mixed effects logistic regression** (= generalized linear mixed model) from the `lme4` package. It will allow you to account for the correlations between individual birds and their baseline parasite risk:

```
lme4::glmer(parasites ~ water_temp + salinity + (1|bird)
```

where `bird` gives a unique identifier for each bird and his observations throughout the seasons. A tutorial for such analysis can be found [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-logistic-regression/).

An *alternative* would be to do **time-to-event analysis**, which wouldn't only evaluate whether birds have parasites but also the time they remain free from parasites. For this you should look into [Cox proportional hazards models with time-varying coefficients](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf). You would also have to format your data differently.

Comment: Thanks so much for this succinct reply!  I'll start with mixed effects logistic.